# Compiling Errors. I fixed all the errors I knew how to fix but im stuck on the rest

Tags: c++, visual-studio, bitmap

I am using bitmap library to project a triangle through an output bmp file which the user inputs information into my Pythagorean theorem function. I am having errors that i don't know how to fix.

**ConsolApplication3.cpp:** (forgot to change name)

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include <direct.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "bitmap_image.hpp"
#include "Pythagorean Theorom.cpp"

#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

int main(){
    float a, b, c;
    float x1, x2, x3;
    float y1, y2, y3;

    bitmap_image image("output.bmp");
    image_drawer draw(image);


    cout << "Enter a,b,c of pythagorean theorom and 0 \n for the value you want to find." << endl;
    cout << "Enter Value 'a' \n";
    cin >> a;
    cout << "Enter Value 'b' \n";
    cin >> b;
    cout << "Enter Value 'c' \n";
    cin >> c;

    float pythag = pythagorean_theorom::p_t(a, b, c);

    //consol output
    if (a == 0) {
        cout << "a = " << pythagorean_theorom::p_t;

        float x1 = 200; //a
        float y1 = 100 + (pyth.p_t(a, b, c)); //a

        float x2 = 200 + b; //b
        float y2 = 100; //b

        float x3 = 200; //c
        float y3 = 100 - c; //c
    }
    else if (b == 0) {
        cout << "b = " << pythagorean_theorom::p_t;
    }
    else if (c == 0) {
        cout << "c = " << pythagorean_theorom::p_t;
    }
    else {
        cout << "You failed... i am disapointed";
    }
    //consol output

        draw.pen_color(255, 255, 255);
        draw.triangle( x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3);

    image.save_image("output.bmp");

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

**Pythagorean Theorom.cpp:**

```
#pragma once

#include <math.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct pythagorean_theorom {
    float inch = 5;


    static float p_t(float a, float b, float c) {

        if (a == 0 && b != 0 && c != 0) {
            // 0 equals nothing for parameters
            //a
            float pyth_c = (pow(c, 2)) - (pow(b, 2));
            float pyth_a = sqrt(pyth_c);
            return pyth_a;
        }
        else if (a != 0 && b == 0 && c != 0) {
            //b
            float pyth_c_1 = (pow(c, 2)) - (pow(a, 2));
            float pyth_b_1 = sqrt(pyth_c_1);
            return pyth_b_1;
        }
        else if (a != 0 && b != 0 && c == 0) {
            //c
            float pyth_a_2 = (pow(a, 2)) - (pow(b, 2));
            float pyth_c_2 = sqrt(pyth_a_2);
            return pyth_c_2;
        }
        else {
            return 0;
        }
    }

}pyth;
```

I dont know how to fix these errors. Please Help.

**Consol:**

```
1>------ Build started: Project: ConsoleApplication3, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>ConsoleApplication3.cpp
1>c:\users\lisa\documents\visual studio 2017\projects\consoleapplication3\consoleapplication3\consoleapplication3.cpp(58): warning C4244: 'argument': conversion from 'float' to 'int', possible loss of data
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.10.25017\include\xutility(2350): warning C4996: 'std::copy::_Unchecked_iterators::_Deprecate': Call to 'std::copy' with parameters that may be unsafe - this call relies on the caller to check that the passed values are correct. To disable this warning, use -D_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See documentation on how to use Visual C++ 'Checked Iterators'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.10.25017\include\xutility(2350): note: see declaration of 'std::copy::_Unchecked_iterators::_Deprecate'
1>c:\users\lisa\documents\visual studio 2017\projects\consoleapplication3\consoleapplication3\bitmap_image.hpp(227): note: see reference to function template instantiation '_OutIt *std::copy<const unsigned char*,unsigned char*>(_InIt,_InIt,_OutIt)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _OutIt=unsigned char *,
1>            _InIt=const unsigned char *
1>        ]
1>c:\users\lisa\documents\visual studio 2017\projects\consoleapplication3\consoleapplication3\consoleapplication3.cpp(58): warning C4700: uninitialized local variable 'y3' used
1>c:\users\lisa\documents\visual studio 2017\projects\consoleapplication3\consoleapplication3\consoleapplication3.cpp(58): warning C4700: uninitialized local variable 'x3' used
1>c:\users\lisa\documents\visual studio 2017\projects\consoleapplication3\consoleapplication3\consoleapplication3.cpp(58): warning C4700: uninitialized local variable 'y2' used
1>c:\users\lisa\documents\visual studio 2017\projects\consoleapplication3\consoleapplication3\consoleapplication3.cpp(58): warning C4700: uninitialized local variable 'x2' used
1>c:\users\lisa\documents\visual studio 2017\projects\consoleapplication3\consoleapplication3\consoleapplication3.cpp(58): warning C4700: uninitialized local variable 'y1' used
1>c:\users\lisa\documents\visual studio 2017\projects\consoleapplication3\consoleapplication3\consoleapplication3.cpp(58): warning C4700: uninitialized local variable 'x1' used
1>Pythagorean Theorom.obj : error LNK2005: "struct pythagorean_theorom pyth" (?pyth@@3Upythagorean_theorom@@A) already defined in ConsoleApplication3.obj
1>C:\Users\lisa\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\ConsoleApplication3\Debug\ConsoleApplication3.exe : fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found
1>Done building project "ConsoleApplication3.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: There are a lot of problems here, but first and foremost, never `#include` a `.cpp` or `.c` or `.cxx` file in another file!  That's why you're getting duplicates from the build system; you get `struct pythagorean_theorom` [_sic_] in `Pythagorean Theorom.obj`, and you get another one of it in `ConsoleApplication3.obj` because it included the `.cpp` file.  Always include only `.h` or `.hpp` files unless you know what you're doing.

Comment: @SeanWerkema I combined the cpp files by including a .h file. I have a new fatal error. "fatal error C1010: unexpected end of file while looking for precompiled header. Did you forget to add '#include "stdafx.h"' to your source?". I have included this at the top of the file as you can see.

Comment: Since you're in Visual C++, it's expecting to find `#include "stdafx.h"` at the top of every `.cpp` file.  You probably don't _need_ precompiled headers for what you're doing, but that's how VC++ is set up by default, and it's easier to do what it wants than to try to turn off PCH support.  Just add that extra `#include` to your `Pythagorean Theorem.cpp`, and get rid of that unnecessary `#pragma once` in it.

Comment: The correct way to set up C++ source files is probably described in whatever textbook you're using, but in short:  Most code goes in `.cpp` source files.  `struct` and `class` and function prototype declarations go in `.h` header files.  `.cpp` files use `#include` statements to bring in the content in the `.h` files that they need.

Comment: @SeanWerkema Okay, one more error.  "error C2011: 'pythagorean_theorom': 'struct' type redefinition".

Comment: That's probably because you defined the `struct` in both the `.cpp` file and the `.h` file.  Types — struct and class declarations — belong in header files.  Functions and data belong in source files.  Don't mix them up unless you know what you're doing.

Comment: @SeanWerkema ... 1 more error. ConsoleApplication3.cpp line 38 " error C2297: '+': illegal, right operand has type 'float (__cdecl *)(float,float,float)'"

Comment: The compiler is telling you that you can't add a number to a function, because you can't: You can only add numbers to numbers or pointers (and functions can _return_ numbers or pointers). Since I can't really see what you have on line 38, I can't know for sure what you currently have. If I had to guess, I'd guess it's probably the line that used to be `float y1 = 100 + (pyth.p_t(a, b, c));`, and it probably now reads something like `float y1 = 100 + pyth.p_t;`, which doesn't work because you're adding a number to a function, not to that function's result.